# Get variables dynamically

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm using Go templates to manage deployments with Helm.

I have the values.yaml file like this:

```
env: dev
config:
   dev:
       myname: Hi
   live:
       myname: Bye
```

Now I'd like to get the values depending on the environment (dev, live).
Like:

```
{{ .Values.config. {{.Values.env}} }}
```

Unfortunately, this way doesn't work because it says:

```
bad character U+007B '{'
```

Is there any way to get the value using others values?

Answer (score 7):

The problem comes from the nested template, this is not how Go templates work.

The solution depends on the internal representation of the data. If it is represented as nested maps, a solution is to use the pipeline global function `index`.

```
{{ index .Values.config .Values.env `myname` }}
```

More info on [pipelines](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Pipelines).

More info on [global template functions](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions).

Comment: Hey! Good answer, but also will work without assigning the variable previously like: 
{{ index .Values.config .Values.env `myname` }}

Comment: @IdirOuhabMeskine You are right, and this is shorter so I've edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The following *may* work. I didn't test it...

```
{{ .Values.config.(.Values.env) }}
```

The full template syntax is found in the [`text/template` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/).