# Use variable to define other variables

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I’m trying to defines some variables in order to make my helm chart non-repeatable

I created a helpers file which contains the following section:

```
{{ $config := .Values.service }}
{{- range .Values.services }}
{{ $config.$serviceName }}
{{- define "{{ $serviceName }}.selectorLabels" -}}
app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .name }}
app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .instance }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

values.yaml:

```
services:
- service1
- service2
- service3

service:
- service1:
    name: service1

- service2:
    name: service2
    
- service3:
    name: service3
```

but it keeps prompting an error for bad character U+0024 ‘$’

Do you know how can I define a variable by other variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get variables dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383273/get-variables-dynamically)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407940/variable-value-as-yaml-key-in-helm-chart)?

Answer (score 2):

Neither the [Go text/template language](https://godoc.org/text/template), [the Sprig extensions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/), nor Helm's local extensions have a way to define a template with a dynamic name.  The name in a `define` call must be a fixed string.  The text/template documentation notes (under "Nested template definitions"):

> Template definitions must appear at the top level of the template....  The define action names the template being created by providing a string constant.

However, templates take a (single) parameter.  Instead of trying to define a separate template for each dynamically-specified value, you could define a single template that produces this content, and then call it with the dynamic settings.

```
{{- define "selectorLabels" -}}{{/* <-- fixed name */-}}
{{/* .name is relative to the template parameter . */-}}
app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .name }}
app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .instance }}
{{- end -}}

{{- range .Values.services }}
{{-/* . is one item from the services list */}}
{{ include "selectorLabels" . }}
{{- end -}}
```

You may find a simpler Helm values structure easier to work with as well.  If you decompose `.Values.service`, it is a list, where each list is a single-item dictionary, where the key comes from a separate list.  You might structure this as a single flat list of settings dictionaries, embedding the item name as a `name:` value within the structure (like for example the `containers:` list in a pod spec).

```yaml
services:
  - name: service1
    instance: foo
  - name: service2
    instance: bar
  - name: service3
    instance: baz
```